# Could I use Akka to start background work (Future)

Tags: scala, akka

is it good to use Akka as a Background Worker?

Like I want to insert some Queries in the Database and then return something to my user, but before I want to schedule a Task which should also Index the Data into another database which doesn't need a callback.

Example:

```
class Worker extends Actor {
    override def receive = {
         case t: Task => 
             Future {
                // do some long running work, which shouldn't affect a user
             }
      }
}
```

Would that work?
And what would happen if I send multiple Tasks at once? will it start running them all at once or will the Actor wait until the Future succeeds?

Edit: Also I would define another case like case r: Reindex => which should reindex all objects, is there any way to lock it so that it will run only one reindex at once? (especially if I have more than one server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work, but you might consider running it with different execution context, if this long running work is really long and blocking.

Actor won't wait until the future succeeds, but you can run into situation when all threads of execution context/dispatcher, that your actor is using, are blocked by these long running tasks.

Read more: 
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

About Reindex:

If only this actor is responsible for reindexing, you can just keep some state variable that tells you if there is current reindexing going.

Can't tell you about inter-server synchronization much. The naive way that comes to mind is to store some flag in DB, that is accessible from all servers.

Comment: So when I create a Akka dispatcher it will create a execution context for scala Futures? Also do I need to start a Future in any way or will a future run if I call no function on it? just Future{println("Hello World!") }

Comment: 1. Simplified - yes. 2. You don't need to start it explicitly. You can try it in your REPL